# « Super nickel chrome » : les alliages du degré supérieur ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, registre-familier, superlatifs, science

On a l'adjectif *nickel* pour « d'une propreté irréprochable » (1918) *populaire et familier, par analogie avec l'aspect brillant et poli du métal* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nickel)), fort souvent avec le verbe être en attribut du sujet, par exemple « C'est nickel chez vous » ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/nickel/54531?q=nickel#54166)). Dans les années 1930, on a une extension de sens pour « parfait, très réussi » qu'on retrouverait renforcé dans *nickel chrome* (1990...) pour « impeccable, parfait » (DHLF/Rey).

---

- Peut-on aussi utiliser l'adjectif en fonction d'**épithète** pour le degré supérieur d'attention, la manière soutenue, appliquée etc., éventuellement le *nec plus ultra*, dans un meilleur exemple que le suivant :

  > Une dissertation/un traitement (super) nickel (chrome).
- L'adjectif *[nickel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel) [chrome](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome)* est-il toujours en usage ; y
  a-t-il similairement d'autres **alliages** usuels (pas en [métallurgie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliage))
  du nom nickel ou de noms d'autres métaux ou minéraux pour le degré supérieur ?
- Y a-t-il une nuance entre *[super](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/super/1) nickel* et *nickel
  chrome* ?

Comment: On n'a rien avec platine, carbone, titane, aluminium... _alu-titane_ non ? J'imagine qu'il fallait être à une certaine époque pour qu'une telle association entre le nickel et l'aspect poli se réalise, entre autres une époque où on devait être capable de faire la différence et où tel ou tel métal était plus courant...

Comment: Le titane, métal dur utilisé pour les outils de construction, indique  la solidité dans l'expression populaire "avoir des couilles en titane" (= ne pas avoir peur du risque). Mais contrairement à nickel, l'usage en dehors de quelques expressions est rare.

Comment: À contraster d'ailleurs avec "avoir/se faire des couilles en or" (être/devenir riche)

Comment: @qoba Aluminium-titane est l'alliage du _Concorde_ ; les freins à disque sont en carbone. Merci pour ces précisions intéressantes !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je peux répondre à une partie de ta question. L'adjectif nickel chrome est encore d'usage. Il est présent sur les dictionnaires d'expressions en ligne (reste à vérifier sur les versions papier). En faisant des recherches sur le net (car je n'en avais jamais entendu parler), je n'ai pas trouvé l'existence de **"super nickel"**. Le superlatif de **"nickel"** est selon moi le **"nickel chrome"**. Le nickel chrome est utilisé pour signifier la perfection. Je n'ai pas entendu d'autre expressions supérieures (à part si on va dans l'univers des pierres précieuses). Dans les métaux j'ai pu répertorier l'acier qui est symbole de la solidité (*"un moral d'acier"*), le plomb qui est symbole de lourdeur (*"un sommeil de plomb"*), l'or qui est symbole divinité (*"des noces d'or"*), le bronze qui est symbole de  éternité impérissable (*"décision coulée dans le bronze"*).

Comment: À propos des noces, les différents matériaux n'indiquent que des durées (voir par exemple [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversaire_de_mariage#Noms_des_anniversaires_de_mariage))

Answer (score 3):

Oui, on peut utiliser "nickel" ou "nickel chrome" en épithète.

> Il a fait un rapport nickel.

"Super nickel", quoique compréhensible, n'est pas idiomatique, en quelque position que ce soit.

Le sens de "nickel" et "nickel chrome" est le même, mais "nickel chrome" est plus intense et ne sera en conséquence pas forcément utilisé dans les mêmes contextes.

On peut aussi utiliser "nickel" pour approuver brièvement une proposition, par exemple :

> Ça te va si je passe te prendre à 17h ?
>
> — **Nickel**

Dans les autres métaux signifiant la qualité, on peut penser à *en or massif* : d'une qualité exceptionnelle, qu'on a beaucoup de chance d'avoir. Par exemple

> T'as vraiment un job en or massif.
>
> T'es con d'avoir largué ta copine, elle est en or massif.

Comment: "super chouette" est comprehensible et correcte, mais a mon avis, pas tres courant. "Chouette" en soi est un peu enfantin, peut-etre (difficile a jauger, bien sur). "Nickel" pour approuver, comme je le dis egalement dans ma remarque ci-dessus, serait a mon avis le plus courant. "En or massif" - je ne sais pas, jamais entendu, mais bien sur, on comprend tout de suite. En dehors des metaux, l y a aussi "beton" pour evoquer la solidite.

Comment: Clarifié la réponse concernant l'usage de "super nickel". "Super chouette" est idiomatique et correct. Cela mériterait peut-être une autre question, car on ne peut pas forcément ajouter "super" à tous les adjectifs, notamment ceux qui ont déjà une connotation superlative quand on les prend tout seuls ; par exemple on peut entendre "super propre", "super sale", "super bon", ou "super mauvais" ; mais il ne me semble pas qu'on entendrait "super magnifique", "super ignoble", "super abject", ou "super délicieux".

Comment: Merci pour les mises à jour, j'ai fait une sélection selon le vote ici. Avec l'or massif j'ai été surpris par le _massif_ car je suis habitué sans. Aussi, nickel pour approuver, intéressant !

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas sûr que ces expressions soient toujours d’actualité en France. C'est un peu de l'argot, et un peu vieillot de nos jours à mon avis.

Comment: J'ai un ami qui utilise "nickel" frequemment ("nickel" tout seul) pour exprimer qu'il est d'accord. C'est plutot une interjection: "je t'appelle avant d'aller au resto?", "nickel!". Je n'utiliserais pas ces expressions en dehors d'une conversation familiere, et tout le monde ne les utilise pas non plus. Mais notez qu'a mon avis, ca ne marche pas avec "chrome". Je n'ai jamais entendu "chrome" tout seul. Allez savoir pourquoi le nickel vaut mieux que le chrome, ou tout autre metal, dans ce cas...

Comment: Mon échantillon de la génération 20-25 me dit que "nickel" est toujours très usité, "nickel chrome" un peu moins. Par contre quelqu'un qui vous parle d'un "super pied d'acier bleu" a dû porter des Pataugas dans les années 70.

Comment: Je me souviens aussi qu'il y avait les "Pieds Nickeles", une vieille BD de quand j'etais plus jeune (en parlant de pieds).