# Que veut dire le mot « nickel » ? Est-ce une expression ?

Tags: expressions, registre-familier

Quelle est l'expression pour le mot « nickel » ?

Answer (score 6):

Je pense que vous cherchez l'expression *[c'est nickel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%E2%80%99est_nickel)*.

> voir être et nickel. Cette expression familière viendrait du monde
>   militaire et daterait du début du XXème siècle. Lors des revues, le
>   canon des armes devait être parfaitement propre. Bien nettoyé et
>   frotté, il brillait de mille feux. Il ressemblait alors au nickel,
>   métal blanc argenté qui, bien poli, brille aussi et renvoie alors une
>   image de grande propreté ! Selon deux autres interprétations, ce
>   terme vient de l’argot des dentistes utilisant un alliage de nickel et
>   de chrome pour les prothèses dentaires inoxydables, donc parfaitement
>   propres. Ou bien du vocabulaire de la salle de bain (robinets nickel,
>   nickel chrome).

Vous pouvez y trouver plusieurs exemples d'emploi.

Additionnellement, googler un peu fournit pas mal des autres sources parmi lesquelles :

> [C'est nickel ! / Nickel chrome !](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/c-est-nickel-nickel-chrome.php)

On y trouve deux significations :

> C'est d'une propreté irréprochable. C'est impeccable, excellent, parfait.

Un article exhaustif d'origine militaire (!)

https://www.defense.gouv.fr/actualites/articles/parfait-!-je-dirais-meme-que-c-est-nickel

*Nickel*, a aussi un autre emploi figuratif. Je l'ai attendu plusieurs fois signifiant *super* !, *génial* ! comme déjà indiqué dans la deuxième source (à savoir : C'est impeccable, excellent, parfait).

Si je n'ai pas répondu à votre question, je m'excuse. Ça serait mieux quand même que vous donniez un peu de contexte et donnez le lien envisagé avec l'image ci-jointe (laquelle à été enlevée après l'édit).

**EDIT**

Une ancienne question concernant nickel sur FSE :

[« Super nickel chrome » : les alliages du degré supérieur ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/super-nickel-chrome-les-alliages-du-degr%C3%A9-sup%C3%A9rieur?rq=1)

dans un registre non familier.

Comment: Les explications sur l'origine du terme ne sont pas demandées mais personne ne devrait s'en plaindre.

Answer (score 4):

L'expression ***c'est nickel !***, que l'on peut abréger simplement en ***nickel !***,  signifie :

> - *c'est impeccable*
> - *c'est très bien*
> - *c'est exactement ce qu'il faut*

On peut donc penser que le lien avec l'image<sup>1</sup> est que notre ami [Busao](https://metro.co.uk/2018/01/28/busao-cat-falling-love-heater-us-january-7266521/) trouve ce radiateur nickel, exactement ce qu'il lui faut pour être heureux.

<sup>1 effacée de la question entre temps</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Le nickel est un métal souvent utilisé pour le plaquage (metal coating) afin de rendre un objet brillant, tout comme le chrome.

Quand on dit "c'est nickel" ou "c'est nickel-chrome", c'est une expression qui fait référence à cette finition brillante, "parfaite" pour suggérer que tout est exactement comme il se doit. Cela peut s'appliquer à la propreté (tout est propre, comme neuf) ou à la réalisation d'un travail sans faute et jusqu'au bout (ex: "J'ai relu ton rapport, tout est nickel")

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary has the following definition ;

> (TLFi) b) Emploi adjectival, populaire et familier, par analogie. (avec l'aspect brillant et poli du métal). **Qui est d'une propreté irréprochable**

Therefore, when someone says "C'est nickel !", they mean "C'est parfaitement propre !".

The English for that is "spick and span" (It's spick and span). There is however a change in the register. Nevertheless, that is the only  translation given by the [reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/nickel/forced).